# AsyncHttpResponseHandler trouble overriding onSuccess metod

Tags: java, android

Fairly new to Android development, and I'm having some problems with overriding the onSuccess methods in the AyncHttpResponseHandler.  My call is just a simple call to an API to get a JSON response.  When debugging, I can see that my code enters this portion of code in the AsyncResponseHandler class:

```
    protected void handleMessage(Message message) {
        Object[] response;

        try {
            switch (message.what) {
                case SUCCESS_MESSAGE:
                    response = (Object[]) message.obj;
                    if (response != null && response.length >= 3) {
                        onSuccess((Integer) response[0], (Header[]) response[1], (byte[]) response[2]);
                    } else {
                        AsyncHttpClient.log.e(LOG_TAG, "SUCCESS_MESSAGE didn't got enough params");
                    }
                    break;
        ...
    }
```

However, even though I overrode the onSuccess method as below, my method is never executed and the AnsycResponseHandler goes immediately to onFinish().

```
    private void getStandings()
    {
        error = "";
        HttpUtils.post("/getStandings", new RequestParams(), new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                refreshErrorMessage();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, response);
                try {
                    error += errorResponse.get("message").toString();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    error += e.getMessage();
                }
                refreshErrorMessage();
            }
        });
    }
```

I have included these in my AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And I import the correct headers:

```
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
```

I would appreciate any insight into why this is happening, as I am completely stumped as to why my overridden method is never called! Thank you in advance!